# How to update table with field Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, window-functions, sql-view

I have table like this:
[image]

Incident_id is foreign key. What I want to achieve it -> create one more column with named position (int). And populate it like this: find all rows for each incident_id and and update each row with index or list of rows I get by each incident_id. exapmple:
incident_id 5 matches with 4 note rows so updated for the position will be 0, 1, 2, 3 accordingly. Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recomment storing such derived information. Instead, you can create a view that uses `row_number()` to enumerate the rows of each `incident_id`:

```
create view myview as
select t.*, row_number() over(partition by incident_id order by id) - 1 rn
from mytable t
```

To get a stable result, you need a column that can be used to consistently order the rows of each incident: I called it `id` in the query. You can change that to the relevant column name (or set of columns) for your use case; you would typically use the primary key column(s) of your table.

---

**EDIT**

If you really wanted to materialize that value in a new column, and considering that the primary key of your table, you would do:

```
alter table mytable add column position int;

update mytable t
set position = t1.position
from (
    select incident_note_id, 
        row_number() over(partition by incident_id order by incident_note_id) - 1 position
    from mytable
) t1
where t1.incident_note_id = t.incident_note_id;
```

Comment: it is for migration one time. I need to populate it to column.ty

Comment: @Demitriush: what is the primary key of your table?

Comment: incident_note_id